# Application Instantiation Error

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am working on the project using joomla+mysql. I copied my project into another computer. Then I set the config file. When I run this project it gives me this error:

Error displaying the error page:Application Instantiation Error:

> Table 'esnew.eu3nr_session' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT 'session_id' FROM 'eu3nr_session' WHERE 'session_id'='h0t2iivrekc9p57g9c9a8tssj1' LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Quite obvious that a table is missing: esnew.eu3nr_session

Comment: Yeah I know, its missing...During the copy its missing? Its working very well on my computer but when I copied to another computer it gives me this error

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Why it gives me this error... I know something is wrong. But I don't know exactly what it was. Can you help me

Comment: From the info you provide we can't tell why the table was not created. Just look up the definition on the computer where it is and recreate it on the computer having the error.

Comment: Thank you very much, juergen. Finally I fixed an error